# How can i update a useState from an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Why does not work the useState for array? i am passing a object for props, now i am printing inside of useEffect his value, at the console.log it have the correct value that value is an array.
i catch that array then i tryed to update the usestate but does not worked

```
const ComponentHeader = ({ csp }) => {
  const [materials, setMaterials] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
      const { mat } =csp

      console.log('Console...', mat)
      setMaterials(mat)
  }, [csp])
```

in the template: i am using antd to show in a list

```
return (
 {materials && (
            <Form.List initialValue={materials}>
```

i put a console inside of useEffects

```
useEffect(() => {
      const { mat } =cp
      console.log('HEEERRREEE', mat)
      
  }, [])
```

this is the output:

```
jsx:26 HEEERRREEE { mat: Array(1)}
jsx:26 HEEERRREEE { mat: Array(2)}
```

should print 2 elements, but only print 1 element

Comment: from where `setInvites` comes?

Comment: Can you add more code/details?

Comment: Try removing csp from []

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: Hey there, i think {} brackets inside arrow function needs returns.. can you change {} brackets to () brackets.. and share the outcomes. Thanks

Comment: change `materials && ...` to `materials && materials.length>0 && ..`

Comment: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/22372

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The useEffect is a hook that handles side effects, and having this second array parameter allows side effects to be run whenever any value changes. so you need to check if csp is changing. Hope this answer your question thanks!